# NetBeans: вопрос по заголовочным файлам C++

Tags: header, netbeans, c++

При создании заголовочного файла (*.h), NetBeans формирует следующий код:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* MAIN_H */
```

Объясните, для чего используется выражение `extern "С"`?

Comment: если я правильно помню и ничего не путаю - у С и С++ разные конвенции передачи параметров, поэтому необходимо уведомлять компилятор о таких случаях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В чистом си нет перегрузки функций. То есть, если известно имя, то параметры понятны однозначно. В с++ есть перегрузка функций, поэтому, зная только имя, угадать параметры иногда невозможно. Для избежания подобного, компилятор делает магию и генерирует уникальные имена на основании имени, параметров и их типов. Обычно это выглядит так "abs@4DZ" - до символа @ - это обычное имя, а дальше закодированные параметры (в этом примере я привел их с головы, скорее всего это не совсем корректная последовательность).

А теперь ответ на вопрос. Указанная инструкция говорит компилятору с++ (для компилятора С она не работает - исключается директивами) что для данных функций в результате компиляции нужно генерировать имена в стиле С.

Это нужно, если Вы делаете библиотеку для других - Если они пользуются с++, то скорее всего у них заработает и без этой директивы (опять же, это сильно компиляторнозависимо, вполне может быть даже от версии компилятора), а вот если библиотекой будут пользоваться из других языков, тогда им будет очень сложно - многие языки не позволяют использовать @  в имени.

Если захотите погуглить на эту тему, то ищите по словам "манглинг mangling demangling decorate undecorate undname"

Comment: То есть, если я не собираюсь делать библиотеку для других, я могу спокойно не использовать "extern C"?

Comment: Если это внутри приложения - то нет никакого смысла (только может мешать). Если даже внутри одного приложения, но как отдельно компилируемая единица (например, в большой компании Вы разрабатываете одну часть, которую будут линковать в большой проект) - тогда делайте. Но только для тех функций, которые "торчат наружу".